# Como colocar o for para rodar a cada 1 segundo?

Tags: java, eclipse

Consegui colocar o efeito do clique no botão mas falta colocar um clique a cada segundo porque está passando muito rápido

```
package gênius;

import java.applet.Applet;
import java.applet.AudioClip;
import java.awt.Color;
import java.awt.event.ActionEvent;
import java.awt.event.ActionListener;
import java.net.URL;
import java.util.Random;
import java.util.Timer;
import java.util.TimerTask;

import javax.swing.JButton;
import javax.swing.JFrame;
import javax.swing.JLabel;
import javax.swing.JPanel;
import javax.swing.SwingConstants;

public class tela {

    //nome do jogador e pontos
    int pontos = 0 ;
    String usuario = "";

    //varieaveis de jogadas
    String jjogador = "";
    String maquina ="";
    int aux ;

    Random numeroale = new Random();

    // janela de exibição
    public void janela(){
        JFrame  ftela = new JFrame();
        ftela.setTitle("Gênius");
        ftela.setSize(400, 600);
        ftela.setBackground(Color.white);
        ftela.setLocationRelativeTo(null);
        ftela.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
        ftela.setVisible(true);
        ftela.setLayout(null);

        //boões 
        JButton b1 = new JButton("0");
        b1.setBounds(120, 220, 80, 80);
        b1.setVisible(true);
        b1.setBackground(Color.BLUE);

        JButton b2 = new JButton("1");
        b2.setBounds(200, 220, 80, 80);
        b2.setVisible(true);
        b2.setBackground(Color.red);

        JButton b3 = new JButton("2");
        b3.setBounds(120, 300, 80, 80);
        b3.setVisible(true);
        b3.setBackground(Color.GREEN);

        JButton b4 = new JButton("3");
        b4.setBounds(200, 300, 80, 80);
        b4.setVisible(true);
        b4.setBackground(Color.YELLOW);

        // exibir pontos
        JLabel mPontos = new JLabel("pontos :"+maquina);
        mPontos.setHorizontalAlignment(SwingConstants.CENTER);
        mPontos.setBounds(70, 150, 80,80);

        //botão de inicar o jogo
        JButton inicio = new JButton("INICIAR");
        inicio.setBounds(90, 10, 80, 30);
        inicio.setVisible(true);


        JPanel p1 = new JPanel();
        p1.setVisible(true);
        ftela.add(mPontos);
        ftela.add(b1);
        ftela.add(b2);
        ftela.add(b3);
        ftela.add(b4);
        ftela.add(inicio);

        //tempo de pause para efeito de botão clicado
        Timer tempo = new Timer();
        TimerTask tarefa = new TimerTask() {

            @Override
            public void run() {
                b1.setBackground(Color.BLUE);
            }


        }   ; 
        Timer tempo2 = new Timer();
        TimerTask tarefa2 = new TimerTask() {

            @Override
            public void run() {
                b2.setBackground(Color.red);
            }


        }   ; 
        Timer tempo3 = new Timer();
        TimerTask tarefa3 = new TimerTask() {

            @Override
            public void run() {
                b3.setBackground(Color.green);
            }


        }   ; 
        Timer tempo4 = new Timer();
        TimerTask tarefa4 = new TimerTask() {

            @Override
            public void run() {
                b4.setBackground(Color.yellow);
            }


        }   ; 

        //fechamento de pausa do botão

        //gerar numeros aleatorios

        //  maquina += num.nextInt(4);


        // acão do botão inicio
        inicio.addActionListener(new ActionListener() {

            @Override
            public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {

                maquina += numeroale.nextInt(4);
                maquina += numeroale.nextInt(4);
                System.out.println(maquina+"\n"+maquina.length()+"\n"+maquina.substring(0,1)+"\n"+maquina.substring(1,2));
                //vez da mqauina
                for (int i = 0; i < maquina.length(); i++) {

                    System.out.println("valor atual"+maquina.substring(i,1));

                    if((maquina.substring(i,i+1)).equals("0")){
                        System.out.println("1 pressed");
                        play("b1");
                        b1.setBackground(Color.white);
                        tempo.scheduleAtFixedRate(tarefa, 1000, 1000);

                    }
                    else if((maquina.substring(i,i+1)).equals("1")){
                        System.out.println("2 pressed");
                        play("b2");
                        b2.setBackground(Color.white);
                        tempo2.scheduleAtFixedRate(tarefa2, 1000, 1000);                

                    }
                    else if((maquina.substring(i,i+1)).equals("2")){
                        System.out.println("3 pressed");
                        play("b3");
                        b3.setBackground(Color.white);
                        tempo3.scheduleAtFixedRate(tarefa3, 1000, 1000);


                    } else{
                        System.out.println("4 pressed");
                        play("b4");
                        b4.setBackground(Color.white);
                        tempo4.scheduleAtFixedRate(tarefa4, 1000, 1000);

                    }

                }   

                //vez do jogador 

                //encerra o jogo
            }
        }); 


        //ações dos botôes
        b1.addActionListener(new ActionListener() {

            @Override
            public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
                play("b1");
                jjogador +=0;

            }
        });
        b2.addActionListener(new ActionListener() {

            @Override
            public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
                play("b2");
                jjogador += " "+1;


            }
        });
        b3.addActionListener(new ActionListener() {

            @Override
            public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
                play("b3");
                jjogador += " "+2;

            }
        });
        b4.addActionListener(new ActionListener() {

            @Override
            public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
                play("b4");
                jjogador += " "+3;

            }
        });

    }
    //  som no botão 
    public void play(String audio){
        URL url = getClass().getResource(audio+".wav");
        AudioClip  audioc = Applet.newAudioClip(url);
        audioc.play();
    }

    public void jlabe (){
        JLabel mPontos = new JLabel("pontos ");
        mPontos.setText("pontos :"+pontos);
        mPontos.setHorizontalAlignment(SwingConstants.CENTER);
        mPontos.setBounds(70, 200, 40, 40);
    }

    public void contagem(){
        try {Thread.sleep(1000);} catch (InterruptedException e) {}
    }

}
```

Answer (score 1):

```
    @Override
    public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
            b3.setBackground(Color.white);
            Thread.sleep(2000); //Aqui você coloca o tempo em milissegundo.  
            b3.setBackground(Color.blue);   
        }
    });
```

Comment: Mais uma vez dizendo, isso não funciona no swing, pois a Thread em questão que será travado, é a EDT, e ela só atualiza a GUI após terminar toda execução em cima da janela, logo, teu código travará a janela por 2 segundos e o botão não vai mudar no click, conforme o OP quer.

Comment: o que eu poderia ultilizar então ?

Comment: tive uma ideia, se ele trava como eu faço ele travar com o botão ficando branco, tipo algum comando dentro dele que na travada ele fique branco

Comment: consegui fazer usando timertask